# Chart.JS Global Options

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, chart.js

I seem to be getting errors in Chart.JS for some reason.  It's related to the global options that you can set.

The is as follows
[image]
Here is my code

```
var chart1 = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d"),
chart2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d"),
chart3 = document.getElementById("chart3").getContext("2d"),

datatest1 = document.getElementById("datatest1").value,
datatest2 = document.getElementById("datatest2").value,

color_bg = "#00b5e4",
color_fg = "#007799",

data1 = [{ value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), color: color_bg}, { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), color: color_fg}],
data2 = [{ value: datatest1, color: color_bg}, { value: datatest2, color: color_fg}],
data3 = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};


//
// #Global Chart Settings
var options = Chart.defaults.global = {
animation: true,
animationSteps: 160,
animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
responsive: true,
showTooltips: true,
segmentShowStroke: false,
maintainAspectRatio: true,
percentageInnerCutout: 70,
onAnimationComplete: function () {
    "use strict";
    //console.log("Animation Done");
}
};

$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";

//
// #Initialise and bind to data and global options
new Chart(chart1).Doughnut(data1, options);
new Chart(chart2).Doughnut(data2, options);
new Chart(chart3).Radar(data3);       
});
```

If you remove the options from the charts they work, if you add options and set them globally as per their documentation you get the error I've mentioned.  Am I missing something obvious or is there an issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
var options = Chart.defaults.global = {
   ...
```

you are setting the COMPLETE Chart global default to your object. Unless you have ALL the Chart global options in your object, this will cause many of the options to end up as `undefined`. The right way to set the global options is like so

```
Chart.defaults.global.animation = true;
Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 160;
...
```

i.e. change the value of the individual properties in `global` instead of setting the entire `global` property.

Answer (score 0):

Global options for charts can be set like this:

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
//Set options
```

So you can just delete the

```
var = options
```

This sets default values for all of your future charts

Please refer to the documentation for further instructions: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

If you want to specify options for each charts do this:

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    // options here
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  All this does is remove all the global options completely.  This means the charts revert to their default setup and the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

First it must be understood that the main property to be tweaked so as to handle the animations is "Chart.defaults.global.animation".

Then keeping this as the base, you will need to adjust the sub-properties as mentioned above and in the documentation page.

So, You can change as follows:

```
Chart.defaults.global.animation.animationSteps=160;
Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration=5000;
...
```

For *positioning of these lines of code,* follow the **first answer by potatopeelings**.

I have tried changing in this way and it works !!!